# Include assets in HTML5 Builder app deployed to Android

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, html5builder

I'm developing an HTML5 app with Embarcadero's **HTML5 Builder** software. I've been able to deploy an app to an Android device. The problem is that all the **"assets"** (images, audios, videos) that I copy in the folder that I'm deploying don't get packaged in the app, so when I run the app in the Android device it can't find them. The same thing happens when deploying the app as a client web-app, the exported folder doesn't have any of the assets.

In the documentation it says that any files that you want to deploy with your code need to be **"added to the project"**. However, I can't find that option anywhere in the software. I see how to add project files (like html, JS, php, etc) that can be edited via the text editor, but not **"assets"** that I want to use in the app.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you right-click your project entry in the **Project Manager**, you can select to add existing files to your project. That is what **“added to the project”** stands for.

Alternatively, when you are deploying your application using the **Deploy to Mobile** wizard,  there is a step which exports your files (it generates a folder that is later to be turned into an .apk file). Right after the exporting step, you can manually add files to the generated folder so that those files are included in your application.